# How can I view deleted files from a pull request using cmd cli?

Tags: git, github, github-cli

`gh pr view $PULL_REQUEST --json files` only gives me lines of addition and deletion but I don't know if the file is completely deleted or not.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best answer to your question, so I'm leaving it as a comment for now. You could checkout the PR and then run whatever Git commands you'd like. [More details here.](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3234)

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/cli/cli/discussions/4766)